# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3' after update pip3

Tags: python, linux, pip

When I use `pip` under Linux I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3'
```

```
$ pip3 -V

...

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.urllib3'
```

My /usr/bin/pip3 :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# GENERATED BY DEBIAN

import sys

# Run the main entry point, similarly to how setuptools does it, but because
# we didn't install the actual entry point from setup.py, don't use the
# pkg_resources API.
from pip import __main__
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(__main__._main())
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling python3-pip?

Answer (score 0):

It seems something "broke" when you installed or upgraded `pip3`.

Try reinstalling:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove python3-pip
$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
$ python3 -m pip -V
pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Comment: this solution did not help