# Why do I get ModuleNotFoundError when installing pip packages

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I try to install a pip package, it shows me an error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.rich.jupyter'`.

I tried to install django by typing `pip install django` but it says `No module named 'pip._vendor.rich.jupyter'`. This issue has been occurring since I reinstalled python.

Comment: Can you share the complete error trace?

Comment: Sounds like there may be a permissions issue with the jupyter module. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16377297/2081835) that _may_ be related.

Answer (score 0):

There might be several ways how to solve this issue, you can try them:

1. upgrade pip via `pip install --upgrade pip`
2. reinstall pip completely - read [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693549/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pip-vendor-urllib3-after-update-pip3) in this post, where it describes in details
3. download `get-pip` to the folder where you installed python: read answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090587/getting-an-error-with-pip3-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pip-vendor-p)

Hope, these hints will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a duplication of [pip3 install not working - No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478573/pip3-install-not-working-no-module-named-pip-vendor-pkg-resources), please try to reinstall pip and try again.

Answer (score 0):

What OS are you using? If you are using Ubuntu or Linux, this thread might be worth a try:
[pip3 install not working - No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49478573/pip3-install-not-working-no-module-named-pip-vendor-pkg-resources).

Have you tried `pip3`? If yes, you could try running it using python as a prefix, eg.

```
python -m pip install
```

You should also look into your PYTHON_PATH and where it points, since you have reinstalled it.

Comment: already tried that ,doesnt work